# Finding out which primary key id not work in a pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Source] | [image: Target] |

Two tables will be joined via composite keys `ID1` and `ID2` via `pandas` `merge`. We have a data testing tool that does the data analysis. It will perform the `merge` and filter whatever rows are not present on the left or right side of the `merge` into an external `Missing In Source` or `Missing in Target` table.

| Missing in Target | Missing in Source |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Missing in Target] | [image: Missing in Source] |

In this example in `Source` the second row with composite key `ABC,345` is missing in `Target`. So that row will be filtered into `Missing in Target`. Similarly in `Target` the second row with composite key `ABC,222` is missing in `Source` so it will be filtered into `Missing in Source`.

For the `Missing ...` tables the business wants to know "why exactly are they missing"--which composite key by row made the row missing? For example, for the row with `ABC,345` in the `Missing in Target` above, `ABC` was present in both table rows but `345` wasn't. Therefore,`ID2` with value `345` is the guilty key for this row.

I should also mention that the version of pandas we are using is 0.23 unfortunately.

Comment: Adding some `python`/`pandas` code that generate your 4 tables would be helpful to potential answerers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: What is the question? [ask] [Help] PS Where are you stuck? [mre]

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] PS This post contains no such clear phrasing.

Comment: Create a composite key from the attributes that weren't used as composite keys initially in the target and source tables and perform an inner join.  Any matches will provide you with the initial composite keys that were different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want [.compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html):

```
import pandas as pd


data1 = {
    "ID1": ["XYZ", "ABC", "EFG", "IJK"],
    "ID2": [123, 345, 789, 111],
    "DATA1": ["car", "truck", "cat", "lion"],
    "DATA2": ["house", "sky", "mouse", "zion"]
}

data2 = {
    "ID1": ["XYZ", "ABC", "ZAB", "IJK"],
    "ID2": [123, 222, 789, 111],
    "DATA1": ["car", "truck", "cat", "lion"],
    "DATA2": ["house", "sky", "mouse", "zion"]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df = (
    df1
    .compare(df2, align_axis=0)
    .rename(index={"self": "df1", "other": "df2"}, level=-1)
    .fillna("")
    .reset_index()
    .drop("level_0", axis=1)
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "source"})
)
print(df)

  source  ID1    ID2
0    df1       345.0
1    df2       222.0
2    df1  EFG       
3    df2  ZAB
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a shame we are using version 0.23 still. I believe compare is only available from 1.1. Nonetheless, you have given me some ideas.